# Know if the Toolbar in Apple Pages is visible

Tags: applescript

AppleScript and Apple Pages.

Is it possible to know if the Toolbar is visible?

What I have tried. I can access to the Menu / View / Show Toolbar or Hide Toolbar. But the problem is that this depends on the language the user uses in the operating system. So, I need a solution that could work in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you were accessing the menu using UI scripting by way of *`System Events`*, which, if I recall correctly, contains a class of `UI Element` called `toolbar`.  You could try and see if the front window in *`Pages`* contains a `toolbar` element.  If it does, it's probably within the top-level of the hierarchy.

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to ¬
    tell the front window of the process "Pages" to ¬
    set toolbarIsVisible to toolbar 1 exists
```

If this snippet is viable, it will assign either `true` or `false` to the variable `toolbarIsVisible`.  The way to check whether this snippet is viable is to run it when the toolbar **is** visible, which should return `true`.

---

#### General Localisation Considerations

Application (and process) names are locale-dependent, so the above snippet needs a little bit of adapting to be fully internationalised, in case *`Pages`* goes by a different name in other countries.  Here's a rough breakdown of various methods you can use to make this locale-friendly:

#### Search for the process using the `bundle identifier` property

Bundle identifiers are another way to identify applications, and these are locale-*independent* strings that are registered with the system, and therefore will be unique to a single application (whereas multiple applications could share the same name).

The `process` for your running *`Pages`* instance can be referenced by way of its bundle identifier (`"com.apple.Pages"`) like so:

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to ¬
    tell the first process whose bundle identifier ¬
    is "com.apple.Pages" to ...
```

The keyword [**`whose`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-BAJJHEFE) performs an efficient search through all of the `processes`, in each case looking up the value of the property named `bundle identifier` for each `process`, returning the first matching `process` object it comes across.  In our case, it'll be the `process` you'd normally reference with `process "Pages"`, but now got in way that doesn't favour any specific language.

#### Use the bundle identifier of the `application` object

A slightly more direct method would be to reference `application "Pages"`, again, using the application's bundle identifier, `"com.apple.Pages"`.  You do this by inserting the keyword `id` after `application`, followed by its bundle identifier:

```
application id "com.apple.Pages"
    --> application "Pages"
```

Since **every** application has a `name` property that AppleScript can retrieve, then:

```
name of application id "com.apple.Pages"
    --> "Pages"
```

returns the name of the application, which on an English-language system will be `"Pages"`, and on any other system will be the localized version of that.  This can then be used to reference the `process`  by name:

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to tell the ¬
    process named (application id "com.apple.Pages") to ...
```

#### String localisation

Probably the best and most recommended way is to lookup the localised string from a `.strings` file, which application bundles keep in sub-folders of their `Resources` folder, named by locale.  It's a set of key-value pairs that containing translations for labels and messages used by the application, including menu item names, application names, dialog messages, and so on.

AppleScript can read the values for a given key using its [**`localized string`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW23) command.  The particular `.strings` file we're interested in is called `"InfoPlist.strings"`(but we leave out the extension when passing it to this command). 
 So:

```
get the localized string "CFBundleName" from table "InfoPlist" in bundle application id "com.apple.Preview"
```

On my system, and I'm guessing yours, this will, of course, just return `"Preview"`.  On a German-language system, however, it returns `"Vorschau"`.

---

Putting this all together, the very first snippet at the top of this script would be internationalised like so:

```
set CFBundleName to the localized string of "CFBundleName" from table ¬
    "InfoPlist" in bundle application id "com.apple.Pages"

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to tell ¬
    the front window of the process named CFBundleName ¬
    to set toolbarIsVisible to toolbar 1 exists
```

Comment: Just curious, why did you switch to using `application id` instead of just `application`? I noticed you made this change a while back but never asked why the change in coding paradigm.  Also, for nubies, which is a large part of the users asking, `tell application id "sevs"` looks cryptic compared to `tell application "System Events"` and it may be confusing for them.

Comment: The first two lines work very well. It gives me true if it is visible. The second part "the first process whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.Pages" I do not understand the code nor the explanation. (I am very new and I am learning)

Comment: Yes, keep the second part and please explain. I am eager to learn

Comment: @user3439894 **Re: "sevs"** is me being lazy when typing on my phone. I don't actually use it myself as it's tied to Apple's creator codes, which aren't used anymore. **Re: `application id`**, this was a personal "good practice" consideration I adopted as bundle identifiers are much less likely to change over time, and only be associated to one specific application, whilst names can change easily from version to version of an application, and need not be unique.

Comment: @Nrc Sorry it took me so long, but I typed this all out on my phone, whilst Googling bits that I had to remind myself of.  I've added a fairly extensive list of options for localising application names, to make the original snippet more internationalised in a general context.  Hope it's useful.  If you have questions, please ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I more or less understand the explanation but I am unable to replicate the case. For instance I cannot check if the Inspector is visible. This does not work: tell application "System Events" to tell process "Pages" to ¬
 set inspectorIsVisible to inspector 1 of window 1 exists

Comment: @Nrc Lolz, no, of course it wouldn't work. You can't make up terms and hope for the best. `toolbar` appears italic and blue (unless you changed this) for a reason: it's a special object that has a very specific meaning meaning in AppleScript. If I had my computer, I would be able to look how to reference the inspector properly. My guess is that it's either a `sheet` object or a `scroll area` object, but it could actually be a few different things. Don't forget, _`Pages`_ is scriptable, so check first if what you're trying to do can be done without hacking the UI. PS. Mind that "¬" in your code

Comment: @Nrc OK, [here's a script](https://github.com/ChristoferK/AppleScriptive/blob/master/scripts/Get%20Mouse%20Position%20|%20Identify%20UI%20Element.applescript) you can use to find the reference to the inspector pane. Copy and paste that script into a new document; compile it. Move your mouse over an area of the inspector that is clear of any buttons or text boxes, or you'll end up with a reference to one of those. So, with the mouse cursor hovering over _`Pages`_ in a spot you're happy with, **but keeping `Script Editor` in focus**, press `⌘`+`R` to run the script. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ The reference to the object underneath the mouse should appear in the results pane at the bottom of your script after it finishes running. If it does, then you'll also have a script copied onto your clipboard, that you can paste into a new  document to have a look, or just disregard it and use what you see in the results pane. The big caveat to this is that I have clung onto High Sierra with dear life, so I don't know what exciting errors that script might generate in Catalina, but I expect it'll be annoying.